# Help to create the right architechture for an extendet opensource CRM

Tags: design, architecture

I am trying to build an extended CRM, using OpenSource PHP-Software. What I have for now are 3 separated systems, that all work well independent from one another. I would like to combine them. The System will have a public and a Private (Internal use only) parts. The Public part is not included in this diagram, but will be added using an API REST. The Databases that are discussed here are for Private use only.

In this Image you may see a very brief overview of these 3 systems. As you can see, these Systems "might" share User-Tables.

[image]

And if one wishes to combine these systems, to my knowledge one has 2 solutions:

1. Extend one of these systems and integrate other 2 smaller systems in it. This will have some drawbacks - for example it wont be that easy to patch or update it. On the other hand, I will have no multiple Tables for "User,User_Events..."
2. Use these systems separately but build a type of synchronization between common Tables "Users,User_Orders...!". Here I am not sure how well this works, what drawbacks it might bring and what kind of synchronization I would have to build (live or using a cron).

Is there an other way? Which would you recommend?

Comment: Are these three systems open source? If so, you should be able to update and patch as you see fit for your integration.

Comment: yes - but I'm not sure that all of them have an MVC structure that can be overridden by a custom plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the user functionality into its own service and have all three consume it

ie

```
IUserService
{
    GetUser()
}
```

Only the user service will connect to the user database. everything else has to call the service

Comment: this would mean, that all the 3 systems must be adjusted (probably in their core) - and don't you think that this will again lead to problems when updating individual systems?

Comment: once you have abstracted the user functionality the three systems will be more simple and easier to update in future. Plus you are bound to want to add extra systems as you progress and these will also benefit from being able to use the existing user service

Comment: further more by hiding the user db behind a service you make that easier to refactor. as you know it is only consumed by that service alone

Comment: I see - that sounds great. And would you keep the user_table in the same DB or have a separate one?

Comment: all user tables in the user db accessed by the user service. separation of concerns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56454/discussion-between-kosha-misa-and-ewan).

Comment: I still have a question - why is it important to have a separate DB for users rather then separate tables in the same DB ?
Every time I want to get information about a user, I would have to establish a new SQL connection. And to my knowledge, in this case SQL JOINs would not work (between 2 DBs).

Comment: if you do a joined query over users and products for example then you have not separated the concerns. If you want to have a nice easy to add features to product, you should aim to keep the individual pieces small and separate.

Comment: otherwise one day you add a feature to Users and break Products